# Controlling CPU freq. in Win7 in an Inspiron 9400

Tags: windows-7, laptop, cpu, dell-inspiron

My Dell's ac-adaptor sort of died on me. The laptop now gives warnings every time I boot it and:

*Warnings: "The power adaptor you are using cannot be recognized. Please use only authentic Dell adaptors with Dell laptops. Your battery will not charge and the computer will operate at the lowest possible speed. Contact Dell support for more detail.

1. The Battery won't charge anymore.
2. The CPU speed is locked at 800 MiHz with a 6.x multiplier... Instead of 1.73 GHz

Now, I don't use the battery that much (it's a 17" laptop) but I can't live with the CPU's new 800 speed...

I found some advice for overriding this on Ubunutu (a kernel trick I can't find the link for) and Win XP (prog: Switch XP); but I need something for win7. Maybe a software over-clocker or real-time freq. controller...

What do you think?

---

### Solution:

Found a fix. Manual, annoying, temporary... *but* it works!

Use ThrottleStop: Here: http://forum.notebookreview.com/acer/452692-acer-throttlestop-thread.html

Comment: best thing to start would be if you'd provide the warnings that you get at boot and some links to the advice you found.

Comment: @WalterMaier, Now?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Until now I had no strong argument to sustain my aversion against Dell. Sorry, but other than contacting customer service I don't have any other advice, and I bet they will only tell you that your warranty has expired and you have to buy a new AC adaptor for some extremely high amount of money.

Answer (score 0):

Where is message appearing, before Windows boots (BIOS) or after Windows boots (Dell driver)? If it's at the BIOS level it could be complicated - Switch XP is only changing the speed step setting while a BIOS level change of the CPU configuration may require real overclocking which involves voltage changes.

However I am guessing the message appears in Windows and it's just Dell software. Go into your Power Options (hit the start button and type power options to find it). Under Select a power plan you'll likely see "Dell" as the selected choice and "Power saver" as the alternative. Dell is a power plan installed as part of the Dell drivers. Look near the bottom and you should see an arrow to show additional plans. Click that and you should see "Balanced (recommended)" and "High performance". Try the balanced plan first - this should give you normal operation again with the CPU only going as fast as it needs to (800 when idle, 1.73 when working hard). If the CPU still won't throttle up try the high performance plan, but be warned that this will run the CPU at the maximum speed step reported all the time. This won't just drain batteries but also heat up your laptop.

Comment: It's at bios and it's a Dell thing... I specifically remember someone saying that Switch XP fixed it on XP but I'm sure from its release date that it won't on 7... And no, powerplans have no effect.